# How to run Spring Boot application with not compileable classes

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I work on Spring Boot application with annotations, and it consist of four parts, that are not pass any data between each other, but rely on same initial task data classes (Think about domain, DTO, services here). I have to refactor these initial tasks data classes and after that all my application services (all 4 parts).

Now I refactored first of four and want to run application to see is it works. I need first module features only for now, though cannot start because 3 other parts is impossible to compile. They are full of errors and I want to fix them later.

**Is there any way to start one of four application parts, while other even not compiled?**

Each part consist of domain and services classes. I not found anything better than comment most of my other parts classes. But this looks ugly. I tried with profiles and some other things but they need class to be compilable any way.

**Update**

As few answer mention maven here what I have in my build section:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: If your code doesn't compile you cannot run it. You need something that compiles.

Comment: Right, that is what I did - comment out not compileable code, but look for some better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the dependency of those modules if your using maven/gradle and mock the other module classes .

Comment: They are not modules, just classes within same application. Are you mean to put each of four parts to separate maven project?

Comment: Yes make separate modules ...In future when you refactor other classes you can maintain easily .

Answer (score 0):

in it maven compiler plugin has a fiegd failOnError  when set to false it continues to package even if there are compilation error

```
<plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-compile</id>
                    <phase>default-compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <failOnError>false</failOnError>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

ref : https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html

Comment: That an interesting idea. I update my post with maven build section. There is no maven-compiler-plugin, though I will try to find is this relevant.